# CLLocation can't be turned off

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

I already do     `[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];`

There is no other active locationManager.

Yet the location manager seems to be active all the time because the arrow sign is in the status bar.

I also use `MKMapView`.

I wonder if `MKMapView` is the one keep looking for locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `MKMapView` uses `CLLocationManager` to get user location. 
You can turn it off by setting property `showsUserLocation` to NO.

Comment: I want to show user location. I don't want it to be updated every time.